# How do I setup an external status page in TeamCity like their standard one that won't require me to login?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

We have just moved from [CCNET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl) to [TeamCity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamCity) for [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

In TeamCity, I can use the ExternalStatus page/widget fine.

We run Cradiator (http://cradiator.codeplex.com) as a build radiator and notifier in our room and I have modified the [Team Piazza](http://code.google.com/p/team-piazza/) TeamCity plug-in to return XML in the CCNET format so Cradiator can read it.

The problem I have is that the modified TeamPiazza page needs authentication, whereas the TeamCity externalstatus page doesn't.

So my question is: how can I make the custom page I have not require authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeamCity provides the [AuthorizationInterceptor](http://javadoc.jetbrains.net/teamcity/openapi/current/jetbrains/buildServer/controllers/AuthorizationInterceptor.html) interface in their Open API that you can inject into your plugin code which allows you to control the authorisation requirement.

*shamelessPlug* This is what I used when writing the [tcMonitor](http://tcplugins.sourceforge.net/info/tcMonitor) status page. */shamelessPlug*

Here is example code on how to use it:

```
    /* Add the objects into the constructor and spring will make them 
       available for you */
    public StatusPageController(SBuildServer server,
            AuthorizationInterceptor authorizationInterceptor,
            UrlMapping urlMapper) {

        // Tell teamcity that auth is not required for this page.
        authorizationInterceptor.addPathNotRequiringAuth(myUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should post directly to the support forum http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/community/teamcity/teamcity and post the answer back here if you want.

Answer (score 0):

If a [Guest User](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Guest+User) is enabled in TeamCity you can access the page with the [HTTP access pattern for guest authentication](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP).

For example if your page is

```
http://buildserver/teamcity/piazza.htm
```

you can access it by appending a */guestAuth* into the URL:

```
http://buildserver/teamcity/guestAuth/piazza.htm
```